# AttributeError: type object 'ContactRequestSerializer' has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'

Tags: python, django, rest, serialization

I have a REST API created with Django rest. Where I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'ContactRequestSerializer' has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'

class ContactRequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = ContactRequest
    fields = '__all__'

class ContactFormSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ContactForm
        fields = '__all__'

class ProjectRequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProjectRequest
        fields = '__all__'
```

I have specified the same attributes in all of my serializers, and I have inherited from the same class, however, the issue still occurs.

I have an API file, where I make the viewsets

```
    class ContactFormViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ContactForm.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]
    serializer_class = ContactFormSerializer

# ProjectRequest Viewset
class ProjectRequestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ProjectRequest.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]
    serializer_class = ProjectRequestSerializer

    class ContactRequestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ContactRequest.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]
    serializer_class = ContactRequestSerializer
```

and then my models:

```
...
class ContactRequest(models.Model):
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    time = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    project_request = models.ForeignKey(ProjectRequest, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

since they all seem alike, except for the relationship between the two of my models, I can't figure out the issue.

Comment: Did you share all the code for serializers? Seems like you defned a SerializerMethodField called extra_actions on ContactRequestSerializer, but did not include a method a provide data for it, namely get_extra_actions

Comment: which version of django and djangorestframework are you using? And show your urls.py please.